# How to get a swift variable into another view

Tags: swift, variables, view

I created this script and want to ask how can I Get de JSON decided date into another view?

```
let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.178.26/iso/loginserv.php")
                        guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }

                        var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
                        request.httpMethod = "POST"

                        let postString = "user=\(self.user)&pass=\(self.pass)";

                        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

                        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
                            (data, response, error) in

                            if let error = error {
                                print("Error took place \(error)")
                                return
                            }

                            guard let data = data else {return}

                            do{
                                let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
                                print("Response data Name: \n \(users.Name)")



                                if !(data.isEmpty) {
                                    self.signedIn = true
                                }

                            }catch let jsonErr{
                                print(jsonErr)
                            }

                        }


                        task.resume()
```

With the JSON decoded data I means the /(users.Name) Variable...

Comment: which other view? you don't have any views.

Comment: Since this is a asynchronous operation, you may need to use some kind of observer so it can be notified when the result has completed

Comment: Don't repost questions. Add more detailed information what you are going to accomplish.